# How do I add a decimal field in a Codeigniter Migration File?

Tags: codeigniter, migration

When writing a codeigniter migration, I am not sure how to go about adding a field of the decimal type. specifically, how do you define the size of the element that is allowed? For example, how would I define the array to pass to `dbforge->add_field()` in order to create a field like the following:

```
price decimal(10,2) not null default 0.00
```

Answer (score 28):

```
'price' => array(
    'type' => 'DECIMAL',
    'constraint' => '10,2',
),
```

Answer (score 6):

```
'price' => array(
'type' => 'DECIMAL',
'constraint' => '10,2',
'null' => FALSE,
'default' => 0.00
),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'price' => array('type' => 'DECIMAL(10,2)')
```

Comment: Your answer would be more useful if you edit it to add some explanation.